I am wondering how do I tell if my KXD Model # 706B 4 stroke single cylinder is charging?
KXD Dirt bike Model # 706B 57cc single cylinder automatic start. Automatic transmission.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Why do you think it is not charging?

Are you familiar with magneto generator systems? Presuming this KXD Dirt bike 706B w/electric start has a magneto system to generate charging power for the battery, the electrical system is below, from https://www.manualslib.com/manual/938881/Zhejiang-Kingroma-Kxd-Series.html?page=10#manual. 'M', I presume, is the magneto, the flywheel with embedded magnets and transformer windings and rectifier as generator/charging system.


Good find! For those who are horrified at the lack of a voltage regulator to control charging, the internal resistance of the battery limits the current and and the electrochemistry of the battery limits the voltage, provided the designers have sized the magneto for the expected battery size. They usually do, and on average it all works out nicely. Old time tractors with a magneto but no generator would use a tail light bulb in series between the rectifier and battery to limit charging current, since tractors typically ran far longer than it took to top up the battery.

Since I've done nothing with KXD dirt bikes in the past, I'll have to give you a general idea on things. Typically, small engines don't really have an alternator like a car does for recharging the battery. I believe it is more of a generator. And then it will only come on engines which have electric start. It should, however work fairly much like any other generator does, that being, it will produce voltage which is greater than the voltage of the battery, which in turn charges the battery. These types of charging systems are linear in the amount of voltage while they are running, meaning, as the RPM goes up, so does the voltage. The reason I mention this is that they don't put out a lot of voltage at idle, but will put out more as the engine goes faster.
Now, to answer your question ... the way you need to check to see if it is charging is to put a multimeter on the battery and see what the voltage is while running. When the multimeter is in place, rev the engine up. You should see the voltage go up as you do. I don't know what it would range in as far as high to low, but should be at least battery voltage going up to whatever the top end is. I doubt that would be more than 15vdc, but that would be a SWAG. (NOTE: There is also an underlying assumption that the battery itself is a 12vdc battery.) If when revving the engine it does not raise in voltage, or even if it might go down, then you can know for certain it is not charging. You'll want to check the battery voltage before you start the dirt bike to make sure you have a baseline voltage number to work with.
